# Does sharing a DbContext across aggregates violate the transactional boundaries?

Tags: entity-framework, domain-driven-design

And if so, what are some situations where it might be an acceptable violation?

Comment: What do you mean by "share a DbContext across aggregates" exactly ? Who owns the DbContext ? Are you talking about design time or runtime ? Why would it violate transacitonal boundaries according to you ?

Comment: I'd add this question to the *"problems you'll encounter when trying to use EF entities in your domain model"* pile.

Answer (score 5):

How the aggregates are stored should not really matter too much.  If you had a `DbContext` per bounded context, say, then you would end up with multiple ARs in the same `DbContext`.

The main issue would be whether you should be manipulating more than one AR in the same transaction.  You should aim to design your system so as *not* to change more than one AR in the same transaction.  That being said, you *may* run into situations where you cannot avoid doing so.  As long as having more than one AR in a transaction is the exception, rather than the rule, then it should be Ok.